# Delete a sql row using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to delete a sql table record from C# thru Linq but some reason DeleteonSubmit is not recoganized,am not sure what iam missing here, please guide me the right way

here is my code

```
          proxy = new ServiceClient("basicHttp_IService");
        //GatewayService.ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient("basicHttp_IService");

        SearchCriteria criteria = new SearchCriteria();
        criteria.UserRoles = new string[] { "*" };

        var stories = proxy.GetStoryItemsByCriteria(criteria);
        var programs = proxy.GetPrograms();
        var Profiles = proxy.GetProfiles();
foreach(StoryProgram sp in lstStoriestoClose)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime LastUpdateTimestamp;
        DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
        LastUpdateTimestamp = sp.Story.LastUpdatedOn;

        if ((CurrentTime - LastUpdateTimestamp).TotalHours > 24)
        {
            //Delete the story from database
            var storytoDelete = from story in stories
                                where story.Id == sp.Story.Id
                                select story;

            //I am trying to delete the record like below
            stories.DeleteonSubmit(storytoDelete);
            stories.SubmitChanges();
            //Intellisense doesn't show the option DeleteonSubmit and SubmitChanges
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me the right way to delete the record in SQL thru Linq

Comment: do you see the record if you stop after assignment of storytodelete?

Comment: i don't see a record,i can see a record adding this code after storytodelete "List<StoryProgram> lstStoriestoDelete = (from story in storytoDelete
                                                                join program in programs on story.ProgramId equals program.Id
                                                                join profile in Profiles on story.ProfileId equals profile.Id
                                                                select new StoryProgram(story, program, profile)).ToList();
                        "

Comment: my problem is, it throws an exception at DeleteonSubmit or DeleteAllonSubmit "System.Array doesn't contain a definition for DeleteALLonSubmit and no extension method DeleteALLonSubmit accepting a first argument of type System.Array are you missing a  using directive or an assembly reference"

Comment: please show where stories is being defined, it should not be an array

Comment: @aw04, updated my op. i call my wcf service to get stories

Comment: @Usher I rolled back your question to show the original code in quewstion.  If you want to ask a question regarding your _new_ code then post that as a new question - otherwise the comments and answers don't make sense.

Comment: sorry i just added my new code in separate answer down below. thanks D Stanley

Answer (score 6):

`DeleteOnSubmit` is for single entities.  Your query returns a *collection* of entities (granted there may be only one entry, but it's still a collection).  You can either use `DeleteAllOnSubmit`:

```
//Delete the story from database
var storytoDelete = from story in stories
                    where story.Id == sp.Story.Id
                    select story;

//I am trying to delete the record like below
stories.DeleteAllOnSubmit(storytoDelete);
```

or explicitly extract one record:

```
//Delete the story from database
var storytoDelete = from story in stories
                    where story.Id == sp.Story.Id
                    select story;

//I am trying to delete the record like below
stories.DeleteOnSubmit(storytoDelete.Single());  // or First, depending on whether you expect more than one match
```

Comment: thanks for you comment,right now my problem is, it throws an exception at DeleteonSubmit or DeleteAllonSubmit "System.Array doesn't contain a definition for DeleteALLonSubmit and no extension method DeleteALLonSubmit accepting a first argument of type System.Array"

Comment: Even i added Namespace "using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Sql;

Comment: C# is case sensitive.  Check your capitalization.

Comment: intellisense doesn't show an option like Delete after stories.

Comment: @ D Stanley, my service returning array,that's why i can't see Delete option.

Comment: OK Now that you've added more context I can see that `stories` is some sort of collection returned from your Proxy.  Does your Proxy have some sort of `Delete` method on it?

Comment: am adding delete method in my service and call when i need is the solution i can see now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your service is returning an array and not a valid linq database object. This is why it does not recognize the methods you expect to see. You need to examine the type and go from there.

You can always right click the service reference and configure to check/set the return type.

Comment: True ,its returning array for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,do your recommend to change the collection type to Generic.list will do the job ?

Comment: No it's not that simple. You need the actual type that relates to you're database table.

Answer (score 1):

I just added delete functionality in WCF service and pass the sql record details to delete the record from SQL that solved my problem.

Thanks all for the suggestion and advise.

```
 foreach(StoryProgram sp in lstStoriestoClose)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime LastUpdateTimestamp;
                DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
                LastUpdateTimestamp = sp.Story.LastUpdatedOn;
                if ((CurrentTime - LastUpdateTimestamp).TotalHours > 24)
                {
                    //Delete the story from database
                    //Check the gateway to delete the record in the db.
                    var storytoDelete= from story in stories
                                        where story.Id== sp.Story.Id
                                        select story;

                   // stories.DeleteAllonSubmit(storytoDelete);
                    List<StoryProgram> lstStoriestoDelete = (from story in storytoDelete
                                                            join program in programs on story.ProgramId equals program.Id
                                                            join profile in Profiles on story.ProfileId equals profile.Id
                                                            select new StoryProgram(story, program, profile)).ToList();
                    foreach (StoryProgram sps in lstStoriestoDelete)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            proxy.DeleteStoryItem(sps.Story.Id);
                        }
```